# Class for modelling a view

Tags: java, gwt, view

I'm writing an application in GWT.

I need to have a class that represents the state that is displayed in a particular view.

The view is for viewing contacts, so there's a contact list, and there are a few types that can be displayed:

- all contacts
- a group of contacts (with a Group class)
- search results (with search query)

type is an enum (ALL, GROUP, SEARCH)

What to do with groups and search results? I need to have the group in the model if the type is GROUP and the query if the type is SEARCH.

The simplest solution would be to make fields such as:

```
Type type
Group group
String query
```

but that doesn't seem very elegant, basically either group or query will always be null (or both for all contacts)

is there any cleaner solution to this?

Comment: A view of what? Desktop, web, android?

Answer (score 1):

If a contact is a class then why not just return a list of contacts and a type

- if all then return a list of all contacts and a type of "ALL"
- if group then return the group of contacts as a list of contacts and the type set to "GROUP"
- if query then return the result of the query (I assume is a list of contacts) and set type to "query"

Or am I oversimplifying your issue?

Comment: I need the group too for highlighting currently chosen group in another view and I need the query for updating history and filling the search textbox, so I'd like to have all those information in a neat little class.

Comment: In that case I think you should follow "SirBraneDamuj"'s advice, if that fits into your design

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you are trying to jam together several unrelated components. What you have here are three different views:

1. you have a Search view which displays your search query
2. you have a Group view which displays information about a contact group
3. you have a ContactList view which displays a list of contacts

If you are displaying a list of contacts for different purposes, then instead of trying to fuse together all of the different purposes into one mess, you should extract the Contact List into its own reusable component.

Comment: there is just one view of a contact list, but each time different contacts can be shown. and these components are related: you select a group to be shown and you get a particular list of contacts, you type in a search query and you get another list of contacts, then you select all contacts and you get a list of all the contacts there are. I'm just not sure how to model this relation in a neat class.